# Split a single value based on two delimiters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string **'100029|0.00,120035|0.00,120083|0.00'**.
I need to split it twice
First I am separating it based on comma and saving in a table. 
Then I want to split based on '|' sign and again. Can't understand how should I do it.
I don't want to use While Loop.
My Code

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (appinv VARCHAR(200))
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE (app VARCHAR(200), inv varchar(200))

INSERT INTO @tab
select Data from dbo.SplitString('100029|0.00,120035|0.00,120083|0.00',',')
select appinv from @tab
```

My desired output is

```
INSERT INTO @tab1 VALUES('100029',0.00),('120035',0.00),('120083',0.00)
select * from @tab1
```

Please help

Comment: sql server version

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following query.

```
   DECLARE @tab TABLE (app VARCHAR(200), inv varchar(200))
    INSERT INTO @tab
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Data,0,PATINDEX('%|%',Data)), 
    SUBSTRING(Data,PATINDEX('%|%',Data)+1,len(Data)) from 
   dbo.SplitString('100029|0.00,120035|0.00,120083|0.00',',')
   SELECT * FROM @tab
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your existing `dbo.SplitString` function, in that case you can try like following.

```
INSERT INTO @tab1 
SELECT LEFT(data, Charindex('|', data) - 1)           AS LeftPart, 
       RIGHT(data, Charindex('|', Reverse(data)) - 1) AS RightPart 
FROM   (SELECT data 
        FROM   dbo.Splitstring('100029|0.00,120035|0.00,120083|0.00', ','))T
```

It can also be done like following without `SplitString` function.

```
DECLARE @tab1 TABLE 
  ( 
     app VARCHAR(200), 
     inv VARCHAR(200) 
  ) 
DECLARE @xml AS XML, 
        @str AS VARCHAR(100) 

SET @str='100029|0.00,120035|0.00,120083|0.00' 
SET @xml = Cast(( '<X>' + Replace(@str, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' ) AS XML) 

INSERT INTO @tab1 
SELECT LEFT(value, Charindex('|', value) - 1)           AS LeftPart, 
       RIGHT(value, Charindex('|', Reverse(value)) - 1) AS RightPart 
FROM   (SELECT n.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS value 
        FROM   @xml.nodes('X') AS T(n))T 

SELECT * 
FROM   @tab1
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------+
| app    | inv  |
+--------+------+
| 100029 | 0.00 |
+--------+------+
| 120035 | 0.00 |
+--------+------+
| 120083 | 0.00 |
+--------+------+
```